# React Axios return undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

fetchApi.tsx
This is where I fetch the api using axios

```
import BASE_API_URL from "../"
import axios from "axios"

const fetchClient = () => {
  const defaultOptions = {
    baseURL: BASE_API_URL,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
};

let instance = axios.create(defaultOptions);

instance.interceptors.response.use(
 function (response) {
   return response;
 },
 function (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
 }
);
return instance;
};
```

Data.tsx
This file is where I put it all together to be call in the main file

```
import React from "react";
import ApiUrl from "../Common/api/ApiUrl"
import fetchClient from "../Common/api/fetchApi";

const data = () => {

    fetchClient(ApiUrl.USER_CURRENT)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data) --> this return what I wanted
        return response
    }) 
}
export default data;
```

Main file

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const result = data();
    console.log("--- ",result)      --> result is undefined
  }, []);
```

When I call useEffect in the main file, data() return undefined but it show me the data I wanted inside data.tsx, any thought?

Inside the main file I want to set the data to useState([])
I was able to get it to work by using normal fetch

```
fetch("some url")
.then(res => res.json)
.then(result => {
    setSomeData(result.data)
}
```

I want to do some url configuration to make the code cleaner and shorter inside the main file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `promises` in order to use data that's not readily available and will be available sometime in future. I recommend the neat `Async/Await` syntax.

```
const data = async () => {

    const response = await fetchClient(ApiUrl.USER_CURRENT)
    console.log(response.data) --> this return what I wanted
    return response
}

useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
        const result = await data();
        console.log("--- ",result)      --> result is undefined
    };
    getData();
  }, []);
```

Comment: @TuanLe does the `console.log` in your `data` function log what you want?

Comment: console.log inside the data file does return what I want as I commented in the code.

Comment: @TuanLe Then it's very strange, try putting a `console.log` before `const result = await data();` to check whether you enter the `getData` or not.

Comment: I just needed await and async inside the const data, doesn't need the 2nd await when calling data(). Thanks @Mahdi

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `data` doesn't actually return anything. You return in the .then() but that returns that inner function, not the outer. `data()` either needs to be an async function or return the Promise. If you convert to `async` functions, keep in mind that a `useEffect` cannot be async.

Generally the pattern for this kind of code is:

```
async function data() {
  // do something;
  return something;
}

useEffect(function() {
  const getData = async function() {
    const something = await data();
    // set state with something
  }

  getData();
});
```

Comment: I don't understand async function data() what do I return here?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `defaultOptions` needs to be outside of `fetchClient` to be accessed by the `axios.create()` method.

Another option would be to leave everything in the same context within `fetchClient`.

```
import BASE_API_URL from "../"
import axios from "axios"

const fetchClient = () => {
  const defaultOptions = {
    baseURL: BASE_API_URL,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };

  let instance = axios.create(defaultOptions);

  instance.interceptors.response.use(
    function (response) {
      return response;
    },
    function (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );

  return instance;
};

export default fetchClient;
```

You also forget to export your module.

Comment: I don't think that the problem because axios.create were able to access the BASE_API_URL which is why it work inside the Data file.